# How can I get the picture of a Facebook event using server side code?

Tags: c#, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, json.net

I'm writing a web app that pulls events data from Facebook, and I can get a lot of the information using an app token, but not the picture, which requires a client token, as documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/picture

I want the code that grabs the event data to run automatically on a server at regular intervals, without requiring a user to log in to their Facebook account.

Is there a way I can get a client token without user intervention? If not, is there another way I can get the event picture?

This is the code I am using to get the event data, using C# and JSON.Net (This gets a list of events created by the specified user - ResortStudios):

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get( "oauth/access_token", new
{
  client_id = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  grant_type = "client_credentials"
} );
 var apptoken = result.access_token; 
fb = new FacebookClient(apptoken);
result = fb.Get("ResortStudios/events");

JObject events = JObject.Parse(result.ToString());
JArray aEvents = (JArray)events["data"];
string s = aEvents.ToString();
List<fbEvent> lEvents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<fbEvent>>(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this but something occurred to me that might work for you. Have you considered something like storing it a non-persistent data store like session state? Then, using the Facebook SDK for .NET, you create an ActionResult for UserInfo, like below. (I know this isn't directly applicable but I hoped it might get you thinking.)

```
//http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/ajax-requests/

public ActionResult UserInfo()
{
    var accessToken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
    var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
    dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id" });
    return Json(new
    {
        id = result.id,
        name = result.name,
    });
}
```

Comment: How long would that accesstoken be valid for? I really want to automate the process so that it can run on the server without any user intervention...

Comment: Hmm. InProc (default) would store it in memory which would time out after 20 minutes. You could back it with either StateServer on the machine running the Web app or SQL Server and retrieve the access token that way. (Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx) But, at some point, your token may no longer be valid (on the Facebook server) and you would need to get a new one.